# Mixed geospatial and categorical clustering

Tags: python, r, clustering

I'm working on a project that seeks to identify clusters in urban development based on location (in lat/lon) and a categorical variable (what the particular site is zoned for). Ideally, the analysis would identify clusters of sites that are 1) near each other and 2) zoned the same. Below is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
 lat       lon      zone
 33.22320 -112.6741 R-43      
 33.45324 -113.0888 R-43      
 33.71800 -112.3885 R-43      
 33.45626 -111.9408 AG        
 33.45746 -111.9313 R-6       
 33.45747 -111.9309 R-6
```

I've seen methods that define distance on just lat/lons using great circle distances, but I haven't seen any mixed clustering of the sort I'm trying to implement. I'm fairly new to cluster analysis so any guidance on implementing something like this in R or Python would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is just a special case of mixed continuous/categorical clustering. If you search for that you should find something, e.g., [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) question.

Comment: I'd **split the data** per category, cluster each, then compare.