# clustering with k means

Tags: clustering

I have dataset with two label class (good and bad), I want to apply K Means on my dataset using python, should I use that label dataset or I have to delete the label class column ?

Comment: K-means clustering is done to give labels to data. You already have those, so why are you applying k-means? What is the problem statement?

Comment: I think the OP actually meant the dataset contains a `binary feature`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K-Means clustering for mixed numeric and categorical data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data)

Comment: Thanks all for your answers , yes my dataset consists of binary features and I want to use clustering to test new samples

Answer (score 1):

Delete the label column.

Assuming that you want to compare the clusters to the labels later, then the labels *must not* be part of the data passed to k-means.

And k-means only works well on continuous variables anyway.