# How to give a higher importance to certain features in a (k-means) clustering model?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-scaling, dummy-variables

I am clustering data with **numeric** and **categorical** variables. To process the **categorical** variables for the cluster model, I create dummy variables. However, I feel like this results in a higher importance for these dummy variables because multiple dummy variables represent one categorical variable.

For example, I have a **categorical** variable *Airport* that will result in multiple dummy variables: *LAX, JFK, MIA* and *BOS*. Now suppose I also have a **numeric** *Temperature* variable. I also scale all variables to be between 0 and 1. Now my *Airport* variable seems to be 4 times more important than the *Temperature* variable, and the clusters will be mostly based on the *Airport* variable.

My problem is that I want all variables to have the same importance. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of scaling the variables in a different way but I don't know how to scale them in order to give them the same importance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot really use k-means clustering if your data contains categorical variables since k-means uses Euclidian distance which will not make a lot of sense with categorical variables. Check out the answers to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) similar question.

You can use the following rules for performing clustering with k-means or one of its derivates:

#### If your data contains only metric variables:

Scale the data and use k-means ([R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html)) ([Python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)).

#### If your data contains only categorical variables:

Use k-modes ([R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/klaR/versions/0.6-14/topics/kmodes)) ([Python](https://pypi.org/project/kmodes/)).

#### If your data contains categorical and metric variables:

Scale the metric variables and use k-prototypes ([R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clustMixType/versions/0.2-1/topics/kproto)) ([Python](https://pypi.org/project/kmodes/)).

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the objective function uses a sum over the features.

So if you want to increase the importance of a feature, scale it accordingly. If you scale it by 2, the squares grow by 4. So you have increased the weight.

However, I would just *not* use k-means for one-hot variables. The *mean* is for continuous variables, minimizing the sum of squares on a one-hot variable has weird semantics.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use k-means clustering algorithm, if your data contains categorical variables and k-modes is suitable for clustering categorigal data. However, there are several algorithms for clustering mixed data, which actually are variations\modifications of the basic ones. 
Please check the following paper:

"Survey of State-of-the-Art Mixed Data Clustering Algorithms", Amir Ahmad and Sheorz Khan, 2019.