# Clustering, Mixed Data Set with Ordinal and Nominal Scale Data

Tags: feature-scaling, clustering

After reading a bit how categorical data can be considered in **clustering**, I came to the conclusion that most of the post do not make **distinction** between **nominal scale** data e.g. colour: red, green, blue, and **ordinal scale** data e.g. size: small, medium, large. However, the distances between the items make sense at the ordinal scale even if they are not necessarily the same between all items.

My questions:

1. Can I simply **convert ordinal scale data to numeric scale** without
   causing much trouble in clustering? I think yes, for the above reasons, but I would be pleased if you could confirm.
2. For nominal scale data, where the distances between the items make
   no sense, would be harder to capture. The easiest way I have found,
   if there are not too many items on the scale, was to break down the
   scale and add a variable for each item. **E.g. originally, we have
   colour: red, green, blue, and we make variable colour_red,
   clour_green, and colour_blue, where each of them can take a value: 0
   or 1.** See the post form Jordan A on
   [K-Means clustering for mixed numeric and categorical data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data).
   It seems to me a valid numeric scale of type ratio as it has a
   non-arbitrary zero value expressing the complete absence of
   something and 1 expressing the presence of something. Do you have
   experience with this in clustering? Is this a valid approach?

Otherwise I know I should use e.g. kproto ([Kproto](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clustMixType/versions/0.1-16/topics/kproto)) for mixed data sets or kmodes ([Kmodes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/klaR/versions/0.6-14/topics/kmodes)) for plain, nominal data sets. Thank you for you responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it causes almost no trouble. The only caution you must have is the possibility of having a regular ordinality where the ordinality is actually irregular. For example, having shirt size 1, 2 and 3 but the size "3" is not three times bigger than size "1".
2. The dummy variable creation is a very valid approach when having categorical variables in your dataset, not only for clustering but for almost every model you could construct.