# Different approaches for categorical non-ordered data clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering

I'm trying to find different clustering approaches for only categorical data in R, so far I found:

1. klaR for kmode
2. cba for rock
3. Hierarchical clustering (agglomerative or divisive) with a categorical data distance: gower.

In [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) question, they suggest kmode, which I've already included

I'm searching for different new approaches, as much as I could find.