# Apply a clustering algorithm on categorical data with features of multiple values

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, categorical-data

Let us I have a people data like gender, age, marital status, education, employment, hobbies.

I want to make clusters of those people, having some similarity/common among them (for example they have common hobby, education, age etc.).

Here there is a sample of my dataset:

[image]

I should use an algorithm which works with categorical data like K-Prototypes but I am not sure how to specifically handle the hobbies, because that feature may have many values from 1 to N.

Comment: Have a look at this question, there are some detailed answers: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data?rq=1

Comment: @RomainReboulleau Yes! But I can't find an example on Internet of a feature with multiple options from 1 to N as the "hobbies".

Answer (score -1):

K-means clustering is based on distance. Whenever you are able to define the distance between two values of a categorical feature, it is theoretically possible, yet not always straightforward, to use the algorithm.

The basic idea that I would recommend is then to give yourself distance metrics over each feature. This may not be easy. You may need to manually set the distance matrices. For example, for the `Marital Status` feature, assuming *single*  is index 0, *married* is 1 and *separated* is 2, you could have the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0.8 & 0.3 \\ 0.8 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0.3 & 0.5 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

If you can't define a relevant distance, you can just have it be 0 if both records have the same feature value, and 1 otherwise.

This would allow you to fully compute the distance between two records in your dataset. From then on, k-means algorithm can be applied as if all were numerical data.

Comment: Kmeans *cannot* use arbitrary distances. Primarily, it is based on the **mean** which does not even optimize euclidean distance. K-means nowhere uses pairwise distances, your answer is wrong.

Comment: This may not be efficient, but the mean can be deduced from distances, see this paper (among many others), which also deals with categorical data: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1410/1410.1106.pdf

Comment: My answer may be incomplete, because the method is not straightforward, but computing pairwise distance may be a solution towards using k-means. For instance, from the affinity matrix based on pairwise distance, you could kernelize your data and cluster with k-means in the projected space. But I guess there are many other ways to go further, which is why I didn't develop further.

Comment: Well, that is a different method then though. Yes, you can also use an embedding like MDE. Or you use k-medoids, which does use a distance matrix. But then don't call it k-means when you are not computing a mean because there is no mean of "hobbies".

Comment: And there are a *lot* of bad papers. An arXiv paper from 2014 with just 2 citations usually is a warning sign that you shouldn't trust it much... Because it likely did not pass peer review.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse what can I do with "hobbies" in this case? That's my problem.

Comment: Well, see the linked **duplicate question** and the algorithms mentioned. K-means is the wrong tool because you cannot compute meaningful means. You need something that is not "means".